# ACCESS Subquery Join

Tags: sql

I need to join a number of tables in Access for a report:

- `Customer`: has all customer info

```
CustomerID| Name
----------+-----------
1         | Jim
2         | Bob
```

- `Order`: has all order data, linked to customer

```
OrderID | CustomerID 
--------+------------
1       | 1          
2       | 2  
3       | 2
```

- `Sales`: has all items sold per order

```
OrderID| ItemID
-------+-----
1      | 1
1      | 1
2      | 3
3      | 2
```

- `Item`: has the cost of each item

```
ItemID | Cost
-------+-----
1      | 5
2      | 30
3      | 15
```

- `Shipping`: has the shipping cost per item

```
OrderID| ShippingCost
-------+-----
1      | 25
2      | 25
3      | 25
```

I want to return the results as:

```
Name | Total ItemCost | Total ShippingCost | Total Cost|
-----+----------------+--------------------+-----------
JIM  | 10             | 25                 |35
BOB  | 30             | 25                 |55
BOB  | 15             | 25                 |40
```

Essentially I want to link customer ID, to their order. Then link item cost to the order, and sum the results per order. Then I want to link the shipping cost per order. Finally I want everything grouped by orderID, and all of the values tallied up.

I have simplified the example to make it easier to be answered, but the query I was able to do in other ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER was as follows (this wont work in Access):

```
select 
person.first_name, 
person.last_name,
"Total Damages",
("Room Rate" * ROUND((A.CHECK_OUT_DATE - A.CHECK_IN_DATE))) as "Total Room Cost", 
"Total Deposit",
SUM("Total Deposit" + "Total Damages" + ("Room Rate" * ROUND((A.CHECK_OUT_DATE - A.CHECK_IN_DATE)))) as "Total Cost Exluding Total Room Cost"
from person
join CUSTOMER
on person.personid = customer.personid
join Hotel_Booking A
on A.customerid = customer.customerid
join (
select damage_charge.HOTEL_BOOKINGID as "DAMAGE", SUM(DAMAGE_RATE) as "Total Damages"
from damage_charge
join hotel_damages
on hotel_damages.HOTEL_DAMAGESID = damage_charge.HOTEL_DAMAGESID
where hotel_bookingid = damage_charge.HOTEL_BOOKINGID
group by damage_charge.HOTEL_BOOKINGID
)
on A.hotel_bookingid = DAMAGE
join (
select HOTEL_BOOKINGID as "ROOM", ROOM_RATE as "Room Rate"
from Room_Charge
join Hotel_Room_Rate 
on Room_Charge.HOTEL_ROOM_RATEID = Hotel_Room_Rate.HOTEL_ROOM_RATEID
)
on A.hotel_bookingid = ROOM
join (
select HOTEL_BOOKINGID as DEPOSIT, Deposit_Rate as "Total Deposit"
from Room_Charge
join Hotel_Deposit_Rate  
on Room_Charge.HOTEL_DEPOSIT_RATEID = Hotel_Deposit_Rate.HOTEL_DEPOSIT_RATEID
)
on A.hotel_bookingid = DEPOSIT
where ("Total Deposit" + "Total Damages" + ("Room Rate" * ROUND((A.CHECK_OUT_DATE - A.CHECK_IN_DATE)))) > 50
group by person.first_name, person.last_name, A.HOTEL_BOOKINGID, ROUND((A.CHECK_OUT_DATE - A.CHECK_IN_DATE)), "Total Damages", "Room Rate", "Total Deposit"
order by SUM("Total Deposit" + "Total Damages") DESC
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmm . . . Based on your descriptions, t`enter code here`his should work for you:

```
select c.name, sum(itemcost) as itemcost, sum(shippingcost) as shippingcost,
       sum(itemcost)+ sum(shippingcost)
from ((customer as c left join
       orders as o
      ) on o.customerid = c.customerid left join
      (select s.orderid, sum(i.cost) as itemcost
       from sales as s inner join
            items as i
            on i.itemid = s.itemid
       group by s.orderid
      ) as si
     ) on si.orderid = o.orderid left  join
     shipping sh
     on sh.orderid = o.orderid
group by c.name;
```

I have no idea what your sample query has to do with your question.  The tables are different, the columns are different, it has filtering conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Query should work in MS Access with a few adjustments:

- Remove double quotes from column or table identifiers. Use square brackets or back ticks instead to escape special characters, spaces or reserved words
- Specifically define `JOIN` as `INNER JOIN`
- Enclose `JOIN` pairings with parentheses including subqueries

Consider below adjusted SQL:

```
select person.first_name, 
       person.last_name, 
       dmg.[Total Damages], 
       (rate.[Room Rate] * ROUND((h.CHECK_OUT_DATE - h.CHECK_IN_DATE))) as [Total Room Cost], 
       dep.[Total Deposit], 
       SUM(dep.[Total Deposit] + dmg.[Total Damages] + 
            (rate.[Room Rate] * ROUND((h.CHECK_OUT_DATE - h.CHECK_IN_DATE)))) as [Total Cost Exluding Total Room Cost] 
from ((((Hotel_Booking h
inner join (CUSTOMER
            inner join person on person.personid = customer.personid) 
    on h.customerid = customer.customerid)
inner join 
    ( select damage_charge.HOTEL_BOOKINGID as [DAMAGE], SUM(DAMAGE_RATE) as [Total Damages] 
      from damage_charge 
      inner join hotel_damages
         on hotel_damages.HOTEL_DAMAGESID = damage_charge.HOTEL_DAMAGESID 
      where hotel_bookingid = damage_charge.HOTEL_BOOKINGID 
      group by damage_charge.HOTEL_BOOKINGID )) dmg 
   on h.hotel_bookingid = dmg.DAMAGE 
inner join 
     ( select HOTEL_BOOKINGID as [ROOM], ROOM_RATE as [Room Rate] 
       from Room_Charge
       inner join Hotel_Room_Rate
         on Room_Charge.HOTEL_ROOM_RATEID = Hotel_Room_Rate.HOTEL_ROOM_RATEID )) rate
   on h.hotel_bookingid = rate.ROOM 
inner join 
     ( select HOTEL_BOOKINGID as DEPOSIT, Deposit_Rate as [Total Deposit] 
       from Room_Charge 
       inner join Hotel_Deposit_Rate 
         on Room_Charge.HOTEL_DEPOSIT_RATEID = Hotel_Deposit_Rate.HOTEL_DEPOSIT_RATEID )) dep
    on h.hotel_bookingid = dep.DEPOSIT
where (dep.[Total Deposit] + dmg.[Total Damages] + 
       (rate.[Room Rate] * ROUND((h.CHECK_OUT_DATE - h.CHECK_IN_DATE)))) > 50 
group by person.first_name, person.last_name, h.HOTEL_BOOKINGID, 
         ROUND((h.CHECK_OUT_DATE - h.CHECK_IN_DATE)), 
         dmg.[Total Damages], rate.[Room Rate], dep.[Total Deposit] 
order by SUM(dep.[Total Deposit] + dmg.[Total Damages]) DESC ;
```

Without actual database, above may still need adjusting. For complex queries, always use Query Designer to build joins using GUI tables. You can save subqueries as their own queries to be joined in final query as tables.

Hopefully, we can convince the Microsoft Access team to one day soon upgrade Access to ANSI SQL standards. To OP and future readers, please upvote the [suggestion](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) (no login required)!